# How hide xAxis milliseconds in highchart with codeigniter

Tags: highcharts

Hy!

I need help with highchart. In xAxis I have datetime formated, that was come from epoch time.
Its displaying the hour:minute:seconds and milliseconds but I don't need millisec.
In codeigniter I have highchart library and I can't find out the solution to hide or remove millisec from xAxis.
Please if somebody have some idea it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Could you convert the epoch time to string format, like '2012/2/29', then add them into an array.

E.g.

`xAxis: {categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']}`

See highchart demo [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic) for example.

Answer (score 0):

If your chart is zoomable you'll have to set the option `dateTimeLabelFormats` for your `xAxis`

```
xAxis: {
  ...
  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    hour: '%H:%M',
    day: '%e. %b',
    week: '%e. %b',
    month: '%b \'%y',
    year: '%Y'
  }
}
```

or you can use the label formatter for the `xAxis`:

```
xAxis: {
  ...
  labels: {
            formatter: function() {
              return <whatever format you wish for this.x value>;
            }
          }
  ...
}
```